# if else condition in a sqlsrv query

Tags: php, sql

I'm assigning a variable to a SQLSRV query that displays the table information in an ORDER BY call.  Here's an example:

```
$fromsite = $dataConnection->SelectAllWhere( "applicants", "loan_purpose='VA Streamline' AND statusdate >= '3/1/2011'", "ORDER BY fromsite DESC" );
```

I want to take the same variable ($fromsite) and do an "ORDER BY fromsite ASC" keeping all the same query information the same.  Can I place this in an "if else" conditional statement?  Or, would a switch work better?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$fromsite = $dataConnection->SelectAllWhere( 
    "applicants", 
    "loan_purpose='VA Streamline' AND statusdate >= '3/1/2011'", 
    "ORDER BY fromsite " . ( $isAscending ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' ) 
);
```

I'm assuming you have some value (maybe a `$_GET` parameter) to decide whether to sort ascending or descending. If `$isAscending` evaluates to `true`, the query will sort ascending, otherwise descending.

What I used there is called the ternary operator (`?:`). You can find it on the PHP comparison operators page (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

EDIT: Assigning `$isAscending` will differ depending on the input passed in... but here are some examples.

#### Checkbox - checked is ascending, unchecked is descending

```
$isAscending = isset( $_REQUEST['input_name'] ) ? true : false;
```

#### Checkbox - checked is descending, unchecked is ascending

```
$isAscending = isset( $_REQUEST['input_name'] ) ? false : true;
```

#### Select drop down - values `ASC`, `DESC`

```
$isAscending = $_REQUEST['input_name'] == 'ASC' ? true : false;
```

#### Select drop down - 0 is ascending, 1 is descending

```
$isAscending = $_REQUEST['input_name'] == 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: I have a $_REQUEST parameter.  Example:  if( $_REQUEST['sortby'] ) { $sortby = $_REQUEST['sortby']; }

Comment: What format is the `$_REQUEST` parameter in? You just need to set `$isAscending` based on your parameter. The method will depend on the type of the input... updated my answer with examples.

Comment: Ack! Never pass user inputs directly to your database, you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks. You need to sanitize your inputs, or use prepared statements.